# how to get element in arrarys at react-native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

this is my code

```
function kakaoLogin() {
  RNKakaoLogins.login((err, result) => {
    Alert.alert("token", result);}}
```

the result is below picture.
[image]
if i change like that

```
function kakaoLogin() {
      RNKakaoLogins.login((err, result) => {
        Alert.alert("token", result.token);}}
```

the result is

[image]

why it doesn't get token value?
how do i get the token value?

Comment: Before your alert could you just dump `console.warn(typeof result)` and check it's not a string? If it's a string that'll be your problem. Then you can ` let x = JSON.parse(result)` and x.token will contain your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 99% sure, that your result is stringified, so thats why you have `{token: ... }`, you should firstly parse response then try to show it.

```
const response = JSON.parse(result);
Alert.alert("token", response.token); // now response is parsed object and property toke is accessible
```